# JMeter : How do I fix the "No. Of Times(N)" the network request may get repeated?

Tags: post, get, jmeter, jmx

I am using JMeter to get the **no of bytes - response timings - request status** for series of requests.

Few request gets called/executed repeated no of times, how can I make sure that My JMeter Test plan repeats those network requests for correct N - No of times.

Answer (score 0):

In your thread group, set the `loop count` to the 'No of Times(N)' you want the request to be repeated.

Comment: The number of times I need to repeat the request that count I am not able to measure as its dynamic.

Comment: You asked how to do it N number of times. You can set it to loop forever, or you can set it far too high, set a longer rampup period, and watch the graph to see when it starts to fail requests. You might also want to look at Ultimate and Stepping thread groups from jmeter plugins.. http://jmeter-plugins.org/

Comment: can't you use IF controller for count of those requests getting executed? start with a counter having value 0 and increase it everytime when you execute req. by using postprocessor for that req. and check value of counter > N if IF controller. Is this you need?